# Spring Boot Facebook Starter how to login several users? how to obtain accessToken or providerId

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-boot, spring-social

I've followed several tutorials and got really close to nowhere understanding spring integration with facebook API, having strong knowledge in other spring modules I found myself surprised...

Every tutorial uses:

```
public <A> Connection<A> findPrimaryConnection(Class<A> apiType) {
    String providerId = getProviderId(apiType);
    if (connections.containsKey(providerId)) {
        return (Connection<A>) connections.get(providerId).get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

As this returns me first connection every time?

I've tried connecting to my app from two different machines and both requests return same facebook profile..

So as usual I went to investigate api what is required to obtain user-specific-connection when stumbled upon method which does what I want:

```
public <A> Connection<A> getConnection(Class<A> apiType, String providerUserId) {
        return (Connection<A>) getConnection(new ConnectionKey(getProviderId(apiType), providerUserId));
    }
```

Ok, so I went trying to figure out how to obtain providerId... I fail, many questions such as:

[How to get providerUserId by providerId, accessToken and secret? (Spring Social)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581432/how-to-get-provideruserid-by-providerid-accesstoken-and-secret-spring-social)

don't make it clearer.

It seems I am not the first to fail understand philosophy of Spring integration with facebook. As to many of us it is obvious that we want to use advanced features where every user needs to have it's own connection to facebook with its own data returned and possibility to login via facebook.

Could you kindly please explain how to get connection/facebook object per user as I am very disoriented by the implementation of this spring module.

Does Spring Social Facebook even support concurrent users logged in to Facebook? It all feels to me like building beautiful Eiffel tower without any doors.

I didn't use Spring Security integration as I felt ConnectController approach will provide more control, but apparently it does not and has biased assumptions. Now looking at Spring Security integration.

Answer (score 0):

I tried thi myself some month ago and found it also very confusing.
For me it looked like as if all this spring-social stuff is trying to identify a user of your web-app interactively using OAuth.

What I was looking for was connecting my spring application to facebook to e.g. post something there.
For this purpose you can use the FacebookTemplate and forget about the provider etc. :

```
public String postOnFacebook(Machine machine, String url) {
    Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
    FacebookLink link = createLink(machine, url);
    // the first parm is the title on top of the message
    String message = facebook.feedOperations().postLink("message", link);
    return message;
}
```

You need an accessToken for the facebook account, which is a different story. Finally this helped :
http://www.slickremix.com/facebook-60-day-user-access-token-generator/