# spring-boot can I use FacebookAuthenticationService to connect with apiKey and appSecret?

Tags: facebook, spring-boot

In a spring-boot based application, I would get facebook user friends using apiKey and appSecret to connect and facebook user Id to identify user (no user access token).

I know that via facebook api graph I can use facebook api endpoint /{user-id}/friends to get user friends list, and I can user the app token instead of user access token.

I'm tryng to instanciate Facebook like  this:

```
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService;
...
Facebook facebook = new FacebookAuthenticationService(apiKey, appSecret);
```

but when I include this line in my code I got this compile error:

The type org.springframework.social.security.provider.OAuth2AuthenticationService cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

inside FacebookAuthenticationService.class there is the import of

```
import org.springframework.social.security.provider.OAuth2AuthenticationService;
```

that doesn't exists in build path.... I can't find a

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-security</artifactId>
```

like the not spring-boot

```
<groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
```

but I can't include the second one 'cause I will get a different error durind instantiation of

```
        Facebook facebook = new FacebookAuthenticationService(apiKey, appSecret);
```

the error is:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from FacebookAuthenticationService to Facebook

I'm wondering if someone can help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, the way you connect does not require OAuth.
You want that the server connects to facebook with the credentials you allready have,right?
Than you have to connect using the FacebookTemplate.
I do this in a project and I have only

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

see also my answer on [stackoverflow 35535091](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530440/spring-boot-facebook-starter-how-to-login-several-users-how-to-obtain-accesstok/35535091#35535091)

Comment: yes, thanks you open my mind! I must to use new FacebookTemplate(appToken); (with appToken instead of user-access-token)